# Self Sign certificate for RabbitMQ but being able to trust that certificate on a linux machine

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, self-signed-certificate

I would like to create a self sign certificate for RabbitMQ that will not point to a domain but rather to an IP as I'd like to trust that certificate on a linux machine but the calls will be done via IP

Is it that possible?

Regards,